# How to resolve htmx-get mixed content problem?

Tags: htmx

I use the following htmx snippet to call an api:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
  <form hx-get="/search/" hx-target="#search-results" hx-push-url="true">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search_query" placeholder="Search">
      <button type="submit" class="my-1 btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This works fine locally, however when deployed (on kubernetes, I don't think that's the point though), the applications resides at an https url: https://search.example.com.

Pressing the button now leads to calling the api at **http**://search.example.com and is blocked by the browser because its [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content).

Comment: i had similar issue recently and i ended up guaranteeing that all content was served over https.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem by removing the `hx-push-url="true"` parameter. But I could not find out how to use it with the parameter added.